# Overloaded method resolution for variadic tuples displays strange results

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, stdtuple

I'm getting strange and unexpected results for this code:
https://godbolt.org/z/8vs87vcKK

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
  template < typename ... t_Tys >
  static void foo( tuple< t_Tys ... > const & )
  {
    cerr << "foo()\n";
  }
  template < class ... t_Tys >
  static void foo( tuple< string, t_Tys ... > const & _rtp )
  {
    cout << "foo( string )\n";
  }
  template < class ... t_Tys >
  static void foo( tuple< string, int, t_Tys ... > const & _rtp )
  {
    cout << "foo( string, int ) [" << get<1>(_rtp) << "]\n";
  }
};
int main()
{
  Foo::foo( make_tuple<string>( "foo" ) );
  Foo::foo( make_tuple<int>( 1 ) );
  Foo::foo( make_tuple( "foo", 1 ) );
  Foo::foo( make_tuple<string,int>( "foo", 1 ) );
}
```

Output is:

```
foo()
foo()
foo( string )
foo( string, int ) [1]
```

First question: I would expect that the first "foo()" would be "foo( string )", why is this not the case?

Then when I change the first call to foo() to this:

```
Foo::foo( make_tuple( "foo" ) );
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zh9G39z61

the output is:

```
foo()
foo()
foo()
foo( string, int ) [1]
```

Question 2: Why did the change to the first call to foo() not generate a call to foo( tuple< string> const & )?

Question 3: Why did the change to the first call to foo() cause the overload chosen by the third call to foo() to change? This one is really weird to me as it indicates a side effect of the first call and that just doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first template is using `cerr`, while the others are using `cout`. Since you used `'\n'` instead of `endl` to end the line, your output is not immediately flushed. This is reordering your output. Fixing this, the first output becomes:

```
foo( string )
foo()
foo()
foo( string, int ) [1]
```

The first `foo()` does indeed result in `foo( string )`, while the third `foo()` was actually `foo()`. The change to the first call to `foo()` did not cause any side effects to the third call.

As for why `foo( make_tuple( "foo" ) )` doesn't use the `string` template, that's because when you pass in a string constant to `make_tuple`, it returns a `tuple<char const * const>`.

Comment: my first thought was that i was doing singin somehow dumb - thanks for pointing it out